# Assertion, forall, and maps: Universal quantifiers does not work with maps

Tags: dafny

In this example, I insert only one value in a map and I try to assert that any two keys in this map is the same. However the assertion fails. Here is the [link](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/igaHt).

```
datatype HostState = HostState(counter:nat, vote: map<nat, set<nat>>)
predicate HostInit(s:HostState, counter: nat) {
  var default: nat := 0;
  && s.counter == 1
  && |s.vote| == 1 && default in s.vote
}

lemma lemma_UniqueKey(){
  var default: nat := 0;
  assert forall s, counter :: HostInit(s, counter) ==>
  (
    // |s.vote| == 1 && default in s.vote // Pass
    (forall t: nat, t': nat :: t in s.vote && t' in s.vote ==> t' == t) // Fail
    // (forall t: nat :: t in s.vote) // Not even this works
  );
}
```

The assertion fails only if I use `forall` to iterate through the map.
Any leads on why the assertion fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dafny does not have a built-in understanding of the relationship between cardinality-one and the quantified property you mentioned. Here is one way to convince Dafny of this fact.

We can factor out the reasoning into a generic lemma about maps.

```
lemma CardinalityOneMap<A,B>(m: map<A,B>)
  requires |m| == 1
  ensures forall x, y | x in m && y in m :: x == y
{
  CardinalityOneSet(m.Keys);
}
```

This lemma just says that if a map has cardinality one, then it all its keys are equal. The proof invokes a similar lemma about sets, on the set of keys of the map.

```
lemma CardinalityOneSet<A>(s: set<A>)
  requires |s| == 1
  ensures forall x, y | x in s && y in s :: x == y
{
  var z :| z in s;
  var s' := s - {z};
  assert |s'| == 0;  // this is enough for dafny to see s' is empty
}
```

This lemma is the corresponding fact about sets. The proof is a bit strange, and relies on the (undocumented, learned-by-fire) fact that Dafny *does* understand that a set of cardinality 0 is empty. So we grab an "arbitrary" element `z` of `s`, and then construct the set `s - {z}`. Then we mention the cardinality of this new set, and Dafny all of a sudden notices that this set must be empty, which means `s` had to contain only `z`, and we're done.

With the lemma proved, we can return to your code.

```
lemma lemma_UniqueKey(){
  var default: nat := 0;
  forall s, counter | HostInit(s, counter) 
    ensures (forall t: nat, t': nat :: t in s.vote && t' in s.vote ==> t' == t)
  {
    CardinalityOneMap(s.vote);
  }

  assert forall s, counter :: HostInit(s, counter) ==>
    (forall t: nat, t': nat :: t in s.vote && t' in s.vote ==> t' == t)
  ;
}
```

You wanted to prove an assertion about all states. To do that, we need to invoke our lemma `CardinalityOneMap` on `s`, but `s` is a variable under a universal quantifier, so we need to use the `forall` *statement* to do this. After the statement, we can re-assert the same fact if we want, just to double check that Dafny is now convinced.

---

Here are a few other answers that might be relevant:

- [Proving facts about cardinality of range sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989897/438267)
- [Proving facts about cardinality of sets of factors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63200052/438267)

---

PS: glad to see you're working through the distributed systems course!